# Generating a Storage Key when making an RPC request

Tags: storage, rpc, hash

I'm trying to make an RPC call to a Substrate node, but I can't generate a proper Storage Key. The Module and Method parts are fine, the problem is the Twox64Concat part. The `sp_core::twox_64` of value `33955c59b47da83d1cade50f724a6993` should return `61cb07b62bdbaa9980` but returns `ef859d4c4bea1c66` instead.

[image]

#### Data storage structure:

```
#pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn addresses_owned)]
/// Keeps track of address owners.
pub(super) type AddressOwners<T: Config> =
   StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, Address, BoundedVec<T::AccountId, T::MaxAddressOwners>, ValueQuery>;
```

The rest part of the pallet can be found [here](https://github.com/chainify/pallet-nolik/blob/main/src/lib.rs#L85).

#### My code:

```
    let module_name = "Nolik";
    let module_name_twox = sp_core::twox_128(module_name.as_bytes());
    let module_name_hex = hex::encode(module_name_twox.clone());
    println!("MODULE {:?}", module_name_hex);

    let method_name = "AddressOwners";
    let method_name_twox = sp_core::twox_128(method_name.as_bytes());
    let method_name_hex = hex::encode(method_name_twox.clone());
    println!("METHOD {:?}", method_name_hex);

    let storage_key = "33955c59b47da83d1cade50f724a6993";
    let storage_key_twox = sp_core::twox_64(storage_key.as_bytes());
    let storage_key_hex = hex::encode(storage_key_twox.clone());
    println!("TWOX64 {:?}", storage_key_hex);

    let twox_64_concat: Vec<u8> = storage_key_twox
        .iter()
        .chain(storage_key.as_bytes())
        .cloned()
        .collect();

    let twox_64_concat_hex = hex::encode(twox_64_concat.clone());
    println!("TWOX64CONCAT {:?}", twox_64_concat_hex);

    let key = format!("0x{}{}{}", module_name_hex, method_name_hex, twox_64_concat_hex);
    println!("KEY {:?}", key);
```

#### The output

```
MODULE "f90f720da6ab97a2d8404b27e705dda8"
METHOD "82074de3756f76dc0e8434b877c54d17"
TWOX64 "ef859d4c4bea1c66"
TWOX64CONCAT "ef859d4c4bea1c663333393535633539623437646138336431636164653530663732346136393933"
KEY "0xf90f720da6ab97a2d8404b27e705dda882074de3756f76dc0e8434b877c54d17ef859d4c4bea1c663333393535633539623437646138336431636164653530663732346136393933"
```

Would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

### Update

```
let storage_key_twox = sp_core::twox_64(storage_key.as_bytes().encode().as_ref());
```

solves the issue and I get the `61cb07b62bdbaa99` hash. But,
there is extra `80` after it. It is possible to extend the original set of bytes and manually add `128` to byte array.

```
let mut with_80: Vec<u8> = vec![128];
with_80.extend(storage_key.as_bytes());
```

But I'm sure it's the wrong way of doing it.

[image]

Comment: Can you try using the `hashed_key_for(k1, k2)` function from here https://docs.rs/frame-support/3.0.0/frame_support/storage/trait.StorageMap.html?

Comment: I could not use it directly because of conflicts in Cargo.toml, but I looked through the source code and found out that I need to encode the source bytes. I've changed `let storage_key_twox = sp_core::twox_64(storage_key.as_bytes());` to `let storage_key_twox = sp_core::twox_64(storage_key.as_bytes().encode().as_ref());` and I got the output `61cb07b62bdbaa99`. That's a breakthrough ) The only difference is that the Storage Key contains `80` right after `61cb07b62bdbaa99`. Still trying to understand the nature of it.

Comment: You should really avoid re-writing these functions on your own if you can. There should really be no issues to import the actual functions provided by `frame_support`, and if there is, you should ask that as a question we can answer fro you in another post.

Comment: I've tried every library out there I could find. Unfortunately, each time I faced some issues and wasted so much time to understand how those libraries work. That's why I decided to make this move and understand how to generate these requests on my own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe all the confusion here is related to the encoding of byte vectors.

Vectors in [SCALE](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/scale-codec/#vectors-lists-series-sets) are encoded with a length prefix represented with a compact number.

> A collection of same-typed values is encoded, prefixed with a compact encoding of the number of items, followed by each item's encoding concatenated in turn.

This is required because all of of a scale encoded blob is just bytes, so if at some point, some arbitrary number of bytes needs to be decoded, the decoder needs to know how many of those bytes should be used for the byte blob.

As you solved yourself, you need to `encode()` the bytes before you hash them, so that the length of the bytes is included in the hashing algorithm.

Lets look at your `storage_key` more closely then, before and after the encode:

```rust
let storage_key = "33955c59b47da83d1cade50f724a6993";
let storage_key_bytes = storage_key.as_bytes();
let storage_key_bytes_encoded = storage_key_bytes.encode();

println!("storage_key_bytes: {:?}", storage_key_bytes);
println!("storage_key_bytes_encoded: {:?}", storage_key_bytes_encoded);
```

> storage_key_bytes: [51, 51, 57, 53, 53, 99, 53, 57, 98, 52, 55, 100, 97, 56, 51, 100, 49, 99, 97, 100, 101, 53, 48, 102, 55, 50, 52, 97, 54, 57, 57, 51]

> storage_key_bytes_encoded: [128, 51, 51, 57, 53, 53, 99, 53, 57, 98, 52, 55, 100, 97, 56, 51, 100, 49, 99, 97, 100, 101, 53, 48, 102, 55, 50, 52, 97, 54, 57, 57, 51]

As you can see, there is an extra `128` at the front of `storage_key_bytes_encoded`.

So you need to also include the `encode()` to your `twox_64_concat` calculation:

```rust
let twox_64_concat: Vec<u8> = storage_key_twox
    .iter()
    .chain::<&[u8]>(storage_key.as_bytes().encode().as_ref())
    .cloned()
    .collect();
```

This results in the correct storage key with the extra `80`, which is just hex representation of `128`:

> 0xf90f720da6ab97a2d8404b27e705dda882074de3756f76dc0e8434b877c54d1761cb07b62bdbaa99803333393535633539623437646138336431636164653530663732346136393933

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you so much for your help